# Kendo Ui Scheduler zoom in and out Button

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

Kendo ui Scheduler, How to add Custom zoom in and out buttons for only Scheduler div? I tried adding zoom effect, but outer div is zooming but zooming effect is not applied for events. For example, in below image, if user tries to change the zoom percentage from 100% to 50 % then scheduler div must resize to 50%.

Below Code i tried
I used $(' .k-scheduler-timelineview').style.zoom = 50 + "%";
but zoom effect is not applied to events.

[image]

Comment: Please add what you have tried before. What do you mean with "zooming effect is not applied for events"? Can you please clarify?

Comment: @FrozenButcher, Thank you for your reply. I have modified my question. please check

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
$('.k-scheduler-timelineview').animate({ 'zoom': 1.2 }, 400);
```

I guess that if the user change the view of the scheduler you will need to aply to other classes like **.k-scheduler-workWeekview** so would be a good idea to extend the logic.